# How can I get div after his appear?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ecmascript-6

How can I get add__deal__btn and do something with it?
When page loads, it does't exist and i can't get it, but after adding it how can i get it?

```js
let addTitle = document.querySelector('.add__title');
let addBtn = document.querySelector('.add__btn');
let tasks = document.querySelector('.tasks');
let addDealBtn = [];

addBtn.onclick = function() {
  let task = document.createElement('div');
  task.className = 'task__card';
  let taskTitle = document.createElement("h4");
  taskTitle.innerHTML = addTitle.value
  task.appendChild(taskTitle)
  addDealBtn = document.createElement("button");
  addDealBtn.className = "add__deal__btn";
  addDealBtn.innerHTML = "Add deal";
  task.appendChild(addDealBtn);
  tasks.append(task);
}
```

```html
<div class="add">
  <input type="text" class="add__title">
  <br>
  <button class="add__btn">Add</button>
</div>

<div class="tasks"></div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Would you like to elaborate this more `but after adding it how can i get it`?

Answer (score 1):

After you have clicked on `.add__btn`:

```
let addBtn = document.querySelector('.add__btn');
addBtn.click(); // <= A computational click standing in for a user click
```

you can grab `add__deal__btn` using:

```
const addDealBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('add__deal__btn')[0];
```

Comment: i understand but if I write like this ii doesn't worked                                            
```addDeal = document.querySelectorAll('.add__deal__btn');

for(let i =0;i<addDeal.length;i++){
    addDeal[i].onclick= function(){
        alert();
    }
}```

Comment: How many `.add__deal__btn` buttons are there? Just the one, right? In which case either `document.getElementsByClassName('add__deal__btn')[0]` or `document.querySelector('.add__deal__btn')` will select the button.

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.getElementsByClassName` to select elements on the page that have a given class applied to them. This returns an array. Then get the first item in the array (or, whichever one you want) using brackets:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("add__btn")[0]
```